# Converting (liters/10km) and (km/h) into liters/hour

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Assume we have some velocity data given in km/h:

$$
\mathrm{velocity} = [10, 25, 40, 55, 70, 90, 105, 120]
$$

and the corresponding fuel consumption given in liters/10km:

$$
\mathrm{fuel} = [2.2, 1.5, 0.83, 0.81, 0.78, 0.75, 0.87, 0.99]
$$
I want to find fuel used per hour. Here's what I have done

$$
\mathrm{distance\ per\ hour} = \frac{10}{\mathrm{velocity}/60}
$$
(time it takes to travel 10 km at a given velocity)

$$
\mathrm{fuel\ per\ hour} =\frac{\mathrm{fuel\ consumption}}{\mathrm{distance\ per\ hour}}
$$

so we can calculate fuel/hour

However, what I obtain is:

$$
\mathrm{fuel\ per\ hour} = \\
[0.03666667, 0.0625, 0.05533333, 0.07425, 0.091, 0.1125, 0.15225, 0.198]
$$

And it does not look very realistic, I think the numbers are too small. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: $lph=lp(10km)/10*kmph$ so why you divide by $60$?

Comment: As Andrea says, there is no need to divide by 60. You’re working in hours, so what that achieves is converting to minutes. And indeed your numbers are correct for units of litres per minute! There’s another error in interpreting km ÷ (km/h) as “distance per hour”—what it gets you is *hours per 10 km* (= time per distance, not distance per time), as your parenthetical description says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When converting different units, I like to think of them as fractions, as I find this a convenient way to actually visualise what is going on there (even though the notation does seem a bit off, but again, this is only to get the intuition behind the calculations). So, the first thing I’d do is convert $l/10 km$ to $l/km$; one can imagine this as follows:
$$x \frac{l}{10\,km}=\frac{x}{10}\frac{l}{km}$$
Hence, a fuel consumption of $2.2\,l/10\,km$ is the same as $0.22\,l/km$. Now, we need to figure out how to calculate the fuel consumption over time, that is, how to get $l/h$ as a unit. We see that
$$x\frac{l}{km}\cdot y\frac{km}{h}=xy\frac{l}{h}$$
by simply thinking of the units as fractions; then, the $km$'s cancel out, and we are left with what we wanted, that is $l/h$. So to sum it up, if your car uses $x\,l/10 km$ at $y\,km/h$, the fuel consumption in liters per hour is calculated as follows:
$$x\frac{l}{10\,km}y\frac{km}{h}=\frac{xy}{10}\frac{l}{h}$$
So, for the first car driving at $10\,km/h$ with fuel consumption $2.2\,l/10\,km$, you’d get
$$2.2\frac{l}{10\,km}\cdot10\frac{km}{h}=\frac{2.2\cdot10}{10}\frac{l}{h}=2.2\frac{l}{h}$$
So, the resulting consumption in $l/h$ would be [2.2 3.75 3.32 4.455 5.46 6.75 9.135 11.88], which also seems a bit more realistic. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, I thought about the cancellation of km, but I was afraid it would be wrong to do so.

Comment: Nothing “off” here at all—this is exactly how dimensional analysis works!

Answer (score 0):

Super simple solution:

$$1 \frac{l}{10km}\cdot1\frac{km}{h}=\frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{l}{h}$$

So, you can play with the unit as if they would be variables (actually, they are).